# Error in POST method in ANGULAR

Tags: angular, api, post, http-post, bad-request

I am trying to perform a post method, When I do this post method using `Postman App` it works fyn but when I do this in angular I get error.

This is my **POST Service**

```
storeServers(comment) {
console.log(comment);
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

let accessToken = this.authService.getAccessToken();

return this.http.post(Staticdata.apiBaseUrl + "/2.2/posts/45754385/comments/add?body="+ comment +"&key="+ Staticdata.key +"&access_token="+ accessToken +"&preview=false&filter=default&site=stackoverflow", {headers})
    .map(
(response: Response) => {
    const post = response.json();
    return post;
},
)
.catch(
    (error: Response)=>{
        return Observable.throw(error);
    }); 
}
```

This is my **SUBSCRIBE Method**, Here i subscribe to the service

```
addComment(){
console.log(this.comment);
this.faqService.storeServers(this.comment)
    .subscribe(
    (data) => {
        console.log(this.data);
    },
    (error) => console.log(error)
);
}
```

This is the error: [image]

Anyone with solution for this please.

Comment: I guess your server needs to configure `OPTIONS` request method (probably just with CORS allowed headers), otherwise Chrome cannot reach server with a preflight `OPTIONS` request which it makes before GET or POST automatically. Postman doesn't send preflight OPTIONS, this is why it works fine. Try with a different browser to see if this is the case (only chrome does it afaik).

Comment: I did it using Postman APP using body parameters it worked fyn. @wostex

Comment: i tried with firefox it gave no errors but response was **Object { _body: error, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Object, type: 3, url: null }**

Comment: Try to look at server logs.

Comment: 400 Bad Request .

Comment: This is obvious, I mean look at error logs on your server, you can probably find more info there than just 400 code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152316/discussion-between-samson-and-wostex).

Answer (score 0):

Angular having security mechanisum to avoid request from unsecure http to secure https rest call. 
The preflight request getting failed in that so instead of post request Angular sending Options request. 
   We can avoid this using few steps .
1. Your system ip should be static not dynamic. Change and check
2. Disable proxy in browser security and check .
3. Use server ip and call request instead of domain name.
4. If none of above resolved your problem then run your server in your local machine and point your local server url.
Hope you understood. Ask me if any doubts.

Comment: There was no ip issues it was just a bad request fixed it by adding body in the post request.